Authentication failure in SNMP4j while processing SNMP informs
In case if multiple agents have same authpassphrase and privpassphrase for different protocols, say

agent 1 is configured with MD5 and AES-128 with authpassphrase and privpassphrase both as TestingPassword
agent 2 is configured with MD5 and DES with authpassphrase and privpassphrase both as TestingPassword

Both agents are configured with SNMP4J notification receiver’s engine-id (i.e. local engine-id or constant engine-id) to send informs with.
Then adding entry in USM users like below
   // authPriv with "MD5" and "AES-128"
    OctetString authPrivMD5AES128EngineId = OctetString.fromHexStringPairs("Constant Engine Id");
    UsmUser authPrivMD5AES128User = new UsmUser(securityName, AuthMD5.ID, authAndPrivKey, PrivAES128.ID,
            authAndPrivKey);
    authPrivMD5AES128User = authPrivMD5AES128User.localizeUser(authPrivMD5AES128EngineId, null,
            null, secProtocols);
    snmp.getUSM().addUser(authPrivMD5AES128User);

    // authPriv with "MD5" and "DES"
    OctetString authPrivMD5DESEngineId = OctetString.fromHexStringPairs("Constant Engine Id");
    UsmUser authPrivMD5DESUser = new UsmUser(securityName, AuthMD5.ID, authAndPrivKey, PrivDES.ID,
            authAndPrivKey);
    authPrivMD5DESUser = authPrivMD5DESUser.localizeUser(authPrivMD5DESEngineId, null,
            null, secProtocols);
    snmp.getUSM().addUser(authPrivMD5DESUser);


USM user table will have only one entry that is of the last user added (because combination of security name and engine id is used as key), so for case when informs from overridden agent (agent 1) are processed it is giving wrong digest which is expected because USM user have localized key from agent 2 and informs comes with localization key of agent 1
What could be done to resolve this issue?

Further research shows, this use-case is not supported in SNMP v3. The same security name (= username) cannot be used with different credentials on the same SNMPv3 engine (ID).
